# Rails Random DB entry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to take a random DB entry. I got it working, but instead of the id I want the name to be displayed. Here is what I have so far.

Controller:

```
@server = rand(Server.count-1)
```

View:

```
<%= @server %>
```

I maybe thought I could do

```
<%= @server.name %>
```

But that throughs me an error:

> undefined method `name' for 1:Fixnum

What's wrong? How could I get it working?

Comment: "I got it working" actually, you didn't. With your current code, it returns random integer in the range of 0 to `Server.count - 2`. What about deleted servers? What about 0, which I don't think it's correct id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `@server` is an ActiveRecord model. In that case you can do

```
@server = Server.order('RANDOM()').first
```

The code you wrote returns a random Integer between 0 and the number of Server records in your database.

Comment: I was about to write the same solution, you were first. +1.

Answer (score 1):

I would add the following scope to the model (depends on the database you are using):

```
# to model/server.rb
# 'RANDOM' works with postgresql and sqlite, whereas mysql uses 'RAND'
scope :random, -> { order('RANDOM()') }
```

Then get a random record like this in your controller:

```
@server = Server.random.first
@server.name #=> returns the name of a random server
```